# python: shortcut to display vertical code horizontally

Tags: python, layout, display

Silly Python beginner's question.

I have a list which is displayed vertically, e.g.

```
l = ['foo',
     'baz',
     'bar',
        ⋮
     'end']
```

I'd like to display it horizontally in the code, e.g.

```
l = ['foo', 'baz', 'bar', ...,'end']
```

Moreover, I want the code to continue on the next line if it would surpass the maximum width.

Is there a quick trick to do this? I am working in the newest, standard set-up of Anaconda Mac.

Comment: That depends on the IDE...

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, I'm working in Anaconda for Mac, standard set-up. Does this provide you enough information?

Comment: @LucSpan Anaconda is a Python distribution, not an IDE, what are you using to write your code?

Comment: @fedterzi. You're right, sorry. The IDE for Anaconda is Spyder, that's the one I'm using.

Comment: Printing **horizontally** should be default. Show us the `code` how are you `print` this `list`.